# How can I pay off tuition fees from a past semester so that I can enrol in school again?

Tags: loans, fees, student-loan, school

I still owe my tuition fees for a university of California school from fall 2010. I have been out of school since then with two semesters to go before I can graduate. I've been trying to take out a student loan for fall 2010 but the loan institutions that I've spoken with so far have told me that I can only take out loans for current or future semesters.

What I'm looking for are institutions that will allow me to borrow money to pay for fees from a past semester so that I can enroll in school again. I'm also open to other options. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4):

I know this will probably be met with derision but...

Get a job and save up the money for school.

This has the benefit of not having a debt accrue that you will have to pay off after you get out of school.  Take an entry level position in a field related to your study.  Sacrifice your desires but take care of your needs.  Anything left over pay off your old tuition and then save for future tuition.

Also when you feel the money you are spending for college because you remember the hard work that went into earning it, you respect it more.  If you get a position in the field you want to study you can look at how to apply those lessons you are learning.  It will make your education more meaningful as well.  If you do well you may have a good job to start out right out of college.

Answer (score 0):

I know what you are talking about and this is what students at UC I know usually do in such cases:

1. Talk with the cashier's/registar's office and see if you have been reported to collections. If you had plans to pay via financial aid, this can be a non-issue, but be sure.
   It's critical to remove your record from collections, if any.
2. Take a loan and find out how the loan will be paid. Most lenders pay the school directly based on what the school bills for the quarter.
   If you signed up for X units in Fall '10 and plan to take Y units in Winter '12, add X+Y units in your list of courses. Those X units could be anything in your course catalog.
3. Once the school sends out the bill and the lender pays it, drop the X units.
   This will give you a check and use that to pay out the outstanding amounts.

Most schools will include all outstanding amounts in the bill for your current quarter, but I am not sure if your lenders has agreements otherwise.

Also, some lenders have agreements in place to send refunds directly to them, but remember, the cashier is king and she can make refunds happen the way she likes, and she is likely to help a student unless you have a bad payment history (collections, bounced checks..)

Comment: Can you expand upon this strategy for those who are enrolled in schools that cap the amount you pay once you hit a certain number of hours (i.e. many schools charge up to 15 hours, but anything beyond that is simply under the umbrella of full time student and incurs no extra cost).

Comment: The OP is long gone, and I was expecting some more information from his side. This is all speculative and I will give it a shot if a similar question comes up later.